# Component inside another doesn't working - React

Tags: reactjs, components

[Code in Atom - lookin nice :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H2nQ.png)

This code won't working and I have no idea why ;/ 
In app it's making empty markup  and under text "zehy". 
I'm new in ReactJs and it's very frustrating ...

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components need to be PascalCase in order to work.  In JSX, lower case names aren't treated as html tags.  Change `<taskItem />` to `<TaskItem />`

Answer (score 1):

React components need to be upper-cased first letter (capitalised).

See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components